# JJOE64's graphview: How to manage orientation change

Tags: android, graph, real-time

What information need to be saved in order to have the same graph when an orientation change occurs?

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    View view = getView();
    GraphView graphView = (GraphView) view.getTag(ParentActivity.GRAPH_VIEW_TAG);

    // I currently have only one GraphViewSeries but I will have one more.
    // I couldn't figure out what to do next in order to have the same graphs
    // before orientation change occurred.
}
```

A real time data is being displayed in the graph. I am not worried about the data obtained during the orientation change process.

Thanks for you support and/or direction.

Answer (score 2):

you have to save the data of your series and restore it. You are totally free how you do this. For instance you could do it like this:

go through all your data of the series and save it as a float list, one for the x values, one for the y values.
One problem is, that in GraphView prior 4.0.0 the internal data-array of the series is protected  so you can not access it.
One way is to override it to change it, the other way is that you store cache your data in a own array.

Way #1:
Create your GraphViewSeries subclass and override it to make the data array public:

```
class DataVisibleGraphViewSeries extends GraphViewSeries {
  public GraphViewDataInterface[] getValues() {
    return values;
  }
  // expose constructor 1
  public GraphViewSeries(GraphViewDataInterface[] values) {
    super(values);
  }
  // expose constructor 2
  public GraphViewSeries(String description, GraphViewSeriesStyle style, GraphViewDataInterface[] values) {
    super(description, style, values);
  }
}

// no use this class DataVisibleGraphViewSeries to create series
```

Way #2:
Create a private member to store a copy of the values. When you create the Series object, save your data to your member.

Prior GraphView 4.0.0 there is also no way to get the series objects from the GraphView object. So the only way is that you store your series also in a private member (e.g. mSeries).

Next step is to save your state.
Saving state:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    View view = getView();
    GraphView graphView = (GraphView) view.getTag(ParentActivity.GRAPH_VIEW_TAG);

    // if you have chosen way #1 and you have your series object stored in a member "mSeries" then you can access the data like that
    GraphViewDataInterface[] data = mSeries.getValues();
    double[] xValues = new double[data.size()];
    double[] yValues = new double[data.size()];
    for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i++) {
      xValues[i] = data.get(i).getX();
      yValues[i] = data.get(i).getY();
    }

    // save it
    outState.putDoubleArray("xValues", xValues);
    outState.putDoubleArray("yValues", yValues);
}
```

To restore the data you have to get the data from the bundle back and reset the series.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // ... create your views and your mSeries member must be initialized here

  if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.getDoubleArray("xValues") != null) {
    double[] xValues = savedInstanceState.getDoubleArray("xValues");
    double[] yValues = savedInstanceState.getDoubleArray("yValues");
    // create data array
    GraphViewDataInterface[] data = new GraphViewDataInterface[xValues.length];
    for (int i=0;i<xValues.length;i++) {
      data[i] = new GraphViewData(xValues[i], yValues[i]);
    }
    mSeries.resetData(data);
  }
}
```

I never tested that code, maybe there are some syntax/spelling errors but at least you should have an idea how to manage it now. This works for one series but you can extend this to work for more, just save the number of your series and go through the names like xValues0, xValues1, xValues2, and so on ...

Cheers
Jonas

Comment: Thank you very much Jonas. The steps were easy to follow with some minor change in codes I was able to test it. I then realized, this will not work JUST IN MY CASE (will work for other) because I have to "appendData" as I am doing real time thing.. I could override the appendData method but because of the setViewPort I have to manage a Queue so I am going to try 4.0 of GraphView.

Comment: Since I couldn't find 4.0 to download, I override the appendData and stored the values on "onCreateView". For some reason the series is NOT starting with the data given in "mSeries.resetData(data)". Any idea what could be missing. [data does have valid GraphViewDatainterface]

Comment: no no, use resetData just after the orientation change. afterwards append it as you do it at the moment. another thing that could make sense, is that you also persist the viewport (size and offset) into the bundle and restore it.

Comment: for some reason the graph is not resetting with the given data and the offset. It behaves as if the data wasn't there... This is how I am updating the ViewPort: graphView.setViewPort(0, data.length)

Answer (score 0):

Everything about the state of your UI.  Every piece of data (unless you can and want to recalculate or refetch it), every change to the UI that can't be recalculated including any data that may have been entered or UI state changes from the user.

Unless you have a completely different layout for portrait mode and landscape mode, I highly suggest setting a configChange in your manifest to turn off  Activity recreation on rotation.  Its just a bad idea, even 90% of Google's own apps turn it off.  It works ok if you have a 1 screen uncomplicated fart app it just doesn't work well for anything of real complexity.  This goes especially if you have any background threads or AsyncTasks going on, as they will not handle reconstruction smoothly and will reference stale UI elements that no longer exist.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I unfortunately do have separate layouts for landscape and portrait mode. And I have to use AyncTasks as I have to process some data that comes in real time before pumping to UI thread.

Comment: Then you're in for a world of pain.  Two options-  you can keep the Activity recreation.  In this case you need to save all of your UI data in onSaveInstanceState as mentioned above, and you're going to need to be very careful with your onPostExecute of your AsyncTasks to NOT update the UI if the activity they're attached to is already destroyed.  You'll also probably need to implement a Loader pattern to prevent making unndeeded requests back to the network to refetch already feteched data, and be careful about launching those tasks to prevent unneeded feteches

Comment: The other option is to turn off automatic Activity recreation.  This means in onConfigChange you will have to manually reload the content view, and then update the UI state of all elements to be the same as the current ones.  But your AsyncTasks will have no troubles and you won't need to worry about needless fetches.

Comment: Sorry for the bad news, but the combo of AsyncTasks (or Threads) and activity recreation on rotation is a combo the devs weren't anticipating when they designed Android.  You get your choice of pain.